# Unble to install requirements for summarization

Tags: python, pytorch, summarization, intel-pytorch

I am following this huggingface github(https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/summarization) for summarization but not able to install packages from requirements.

Command used:

> pip install -r requirements.txt

For your information I am trying this Intel oneapi devcloud.Please find the below error.

```html
env: ‘pkg-config’: No such file or directory
    Failed to find sentencepiece pkg-config
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/home/uxxxxx/.conda/envs/env/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/home/uxxxx/tmp/pip-install-ld2o4xe1/sentencepiece/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /home/uxxxxx/tmp/pip-record-tl0qz8f6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /home/uxxxxx/tmp/pip-install-ld2o4xe1/sentencepiece/

Please use "pip install --user <package>" to install user packages.
Please visit the forums at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-devcloud
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pkg-config and sentencepiece separately.

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
pip3 install sentencepiece== 0.19.2
```

Related source: [Link](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/505)

Also, follow the steps which @Abhijeet has mentioned below. That's kinda obvious so not reiterating it.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you can successfully run the latest versions of the example scripts, you have to install the library from source and install some example-specific requirements.

To do this, execute the following steps in a new virtual environment:

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformerscd transformers
pip install .
```

Then cd in the example folder of your choice and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing sentencepiece through brew then pip install

```
brew install sentencepiece
pip3 install sentencepiece
```

Then install the original package you were trying to install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).